# Linux - Create a menu that appears even over fullscreen applications

Tags: linux, hover, gtk, fullscreen

I'm developing a Linux application (menu like) that will perform tasks such as taking screenshots, connect to network, and so on. Until now, it is using Java 8 with JavaFX. It will work on an environment where we have an application that I don't have control (an GTK app running in fullscreen). The idea is that if the user moves the mouse to the bottom of the fullscreen app, the menu will show and the user can perform the actions.

I've searched on the Internet and could not find any hints on how to make this menu appears even over fullscreen apps. Can anyone give me directions on how to do this?

The menu should behave like the one in the picture below (Virtualbox running in fullscreen). In this case, when the user moves the mouse to the bottom of the screen, the menu will pop.

[image: Menu on Fullscreen app]

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I found an article for a new feature since JavaFX version 8u20 that got a new feature for the Stage.

http://www.javafxapps.in/tutorial/Show-javafx-Stage-Always-on-Top.html

Comment: I tried it for the normal Desktop and it stays on top. I didn't try if it works with fullscreen-applications like games and so on ^^